# css column-count: column contents is getting broken by internal divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use the CSS column-count feature, however I am running into some strange behaviour.

The column contents are getting broken.

[image: getting broken]

I am using Bootstrap 3, and am trying to fill the columns with bootstrap panels. But the panels are getting broken/split when it by the CSS column-count.

I have tried wrapping the panels in another div tag, but this doesnt make any difference.

This is an example of an item that is in a column:

```
<div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star yelloStar"></span>
            <label class="float-left">name</label>               
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">    
            <span>text</span> <a href="#" class="btn btn-link">read    more</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right">ADD</a>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The panels (class `.panel`) will have to be displayed as an `inline-block` and then their `width` will need to set to `100%`. It's best to isolate this modification of `.panel` to the `div` with the column-count set so you don't affect panels not in columns. For example:

```css
.my-col-count-style .panel {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here is a [Codepen.io example](http://codepen.io/atadams/pen/dMqjGR).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something like this
[image]

Try below code

```
<head>
  <style>
    .divElem{
      display:inline-block;
     }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="divElem">
    <div class="panel panel-default tick">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star yelloStar"></span>
        <label class="float-left">name</label>               
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">    
        <span>text</span> <a href="#" class="btn btn-link">read    more</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right">ADD</a>
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="divElem">
    <h1> name</h1>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star yelloStar"></span>
        <label class="float-left">name</label>               
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">    
        <span>text</span> <a href="#" class="btn btn-link">read    more</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right">ADD</a>
      </div>    
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Also you can try grid system of bootstrap to achieve this.